# Can not update google/cloud-firestore [composer]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, composer-php

Now, I am using google/cloud-firestore ^0.8.1 and I want to update this library to latest version (0.14.0).
My composer.json now looks like:

```
"require": {
"grpc/grpc": "^1.10",
"google/protobuf": "^3.5",
"google/gax": "^0.31.3",
"google/cloud-firestore": "^0.8.1",
"firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0",
}
```

When I try to update firestore library with `php composer.phar require  google/cloud-firestore`
 , I got:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for google/cloud-firestore ^0.14.0 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v0.14.0].
    - google/cloud-firestore v0.14.0 requires google/gax ^0.37 -> satisfiable by google/gax[0.37.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

After that, I tried with  `php composer.phar require  google/gax` and got:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - google/cloud-firestore v0.8.1 requires google/gax ^0.31.1 -> satisfiable by google/gax[0.31.x-dev].
    - google/cloud-firestore v0.8.1 requires google/gax ^0.31.1 -> satisfiable by google/gax[0.31.x-dev].
    - google/cloud-firestore v0.8.1 requires google/gax ^0.31.1 -> satisfiable by google/gax[0.31.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: google/gax[0.37.0, 0.31.x-dev].
    - Installation request for google/gax ^0.37 -> satisfiable by google/gax[0.37.0].
    - Installation request for google/cloud-firestore ^0.8.1 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v0.8.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I added `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to composer.json but that didn't resolve problem. 
How to properly update these libraries and fix dependencies between them?

Comment: Please don't use images to show code and errors.  It's better to copy the text directly into your question so that it's easier to read and search. Also, FYI, the latest version of the Firestore node SDK is 0.16.1, not 0.14.0.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for your advice about posting questions. I saw that latest version of firestore for PHP is 0.14.0 here https://packagist.org/packages/google/cloud-firestore and here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-firestore.

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly and thought you were talking about node instead of PHP.  It's not too late to edit your question to show text instead of picture.

Comment: @DougStevenson, updated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantic versioning operator (`^`) behaves slightly different with pre-1.0 releases (see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-):

> For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind and treats `^0.3` as ?`>=0.3.0 <0.4.0`.

This means that you will have to update both packages like this:

```
composer require google/cloud-firestore:^0.14 google/gax:^0.37
```

Comment: Thank you @xabbuh for you answer, but proposed solution didn't help. Even if I try to update google/cloud-firestore to version ^0.9.1 I get dependency of google/proto-client instead of google/gax. When I tried to update google/proto-client I got error, that I can not do it because google/cloud-firestore requires older version..

Comment: Can you please post the full error message you get when you execute the command from my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just posted answer with solution :)

Answer (score 0):

With @xabbuh help, I find out solution. 
There wasn't problem just in semantic versioning operator (^) but in packages I wanted to update. 
I needed to install/update all packages that are needed for updating firestore on version 0.14. I called `composer require google/cloud-firestore:^0.14` and after that `composer require google/gax:^0.37` and after that tried with reverse order, but there were similar error messages.
When I included all packages needed into require command for updating firestore package it passed well.
So, here are working command:

```
composer require google/cloud-firestore:^0.14 google/gax:^0.37 google/auth:^1.3 google/grpc-gcp:^0.1.0 grpc/grpc:^1.13.0 google/cloud-core:^1.23
```